# How do i pass arguments in shell script in jenkinsfile?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, user-input

I created a Jenkinsfile and there is a step where i execute a shell script.
But I want run time arguments in my shell script by Jenkins's Input method.

Following is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
```

and I want to run following command in pipeline.

```
sh '''sh run.sh ''' + input id: 'Pass arguments', message: 'pass arguments', ok: 'done', parameters: [text(defaultValue: '', description: 'give arguments', name: 'give')]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the input from the user. Input step register the value to environment variable. So you can do something like this.

```
node('master'){
  def input = input message: 'Write some thing', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'SOMETHING', trim: false)]
  echo input
  sh "echo ${input}"
}
```

Comment: I use the same as you mention. but can't able to print arguments.                   [Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] input
Input requested
Approved by admin
[Pipeline] sh
+ sh run.sh


[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

Comment: I also got an error --> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: **SOMETHING** for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: Sorry, I confused usage with other step. Updated the usage example